# Syntax error near "#5018" in android sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-delete

In Android application, I have a database to store contacts. In that, I have a "Number" column of "Text" type.
I get `syntax error near: "#5018" (code 1)` error while executing below query:
`string passedNumber = "#5018";
 db.delete("Contact_Table, "Number=" + passedNumber, null);`

But If I use quotte aroung number like:
`db.delete("Contact_Table, "Number='" + passedNumber + "'", null);`

 then it is working properly. 

**My concern is why it is giving error although I have `Number` column of `Text` type.**

Comment: You should pass the value in `single quote`

Comment: But why? `Number` column is of string type and it is working find when I pass digits only in Number, no any other characters. It should give error every time if I make query without `single quote`.

Comment: Try to read a Log callstack error:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `#5018` is syntactically not a number or any other valid construct. When you enclose it in single quotes as `'#5018'` it becomes a string literal and that is syntactically correct. `5018` would be a syntactically valid numeric literal.

Column type affinities have nothing to do with literal syntax.

Comment: Does sqlite make any conversion while compiling query.?

Comment: @pratik03 Read on about type affinities and conversions in https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html